# Tengo un input number y cuando un usuario ingresa por ejemplo 20. el resultado es vacío

Tags: javascript, html5, input-type

```js
function events(element){
      console.log(element.value)
    }
```

```html
 <input type="number" step=".1" min="1" max="100" oninput="events(this)">
```

Resultado obtenidos

- 20 = correcto
- 20.5 = correcto
- 20,5 = correcto
- 20, = correcto y me retorna 20
- **20. = incorrecto y me retorna vacío**

Resultado esperado

- 20. = correcto y que me retorne 20

Comment: Hice lo que me has dicho y el valor resultando es 0, y debería ser 20

Comment: Lo que entendí fue que multiplicará el valor por 1 
`console.log('valor', element.value * 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer, es parsear a float el value de input, para convertirlo a numero.

```
var a = parseFloat("20");
var b = parseFloat("20.");
var c = parseFloat("20,");
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo he intentado y me retorna NaN 
console.log('valor', parseInt(element.value) + ' a')

Comment: Por que estás metiendo un 'a' tu ??

Comment: Intentaba replicar tu ejemplo, pero igual sin el 'a' no me funciona

Comment: Ahi te lo deje, con float ya que recorde que quieres los decimales, y además, te demuestro como funciona en consola.

Comment: Es que si estas quemando los datos lógicamente va a funcionar, pero el problema es el input type="nnumber", porque cuando se ingresa 2. retorna vacío

Comment: Te lo dije antes, por que al terminar en . es un string, y recibe numbers